# facebook realtime updates not working

Tags: facebook-graph-api, callback, user-permissions, real-time-updates

I've configured my app to "listen" on events on the user object - changes in the name of the user.
Also, I've configured it to "listen" on events on the permissions object - changes in the permissions of a user.

I succeeded to subscribe successful - it is verified.
So the GET operation works good , however the POST operation doesn't seem to work.
Notice that I was able to work with my callback server with GET and POST successfuly, but it seems that Facebook real time updates doesn't work.

Anyone else experiencing this issue? are there any special points on configuring the callback server?

I've found several remarks on this issue, but I still can't understand if the updates aren't working because of my mistakes or because Facebook updates doesn't work.

For example, this link describes the same issue:
[Not receiving realtime updates at all from Facebook](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11724241/not-receiving-realtime-updates-at-all-from-facebook)

Also, there is an open bug on this issue, reported here: but again I'm not sure if it is my bad:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/267220196722379?browse=search_501c8eb30d8239e58192973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that it was problem at my side.
I'm working with a RESTful WCF as the callback server and I had some difficulties with the application/json content type.
I actually got the messages from Facebook server but the WCF rejected the requests because of the application/json content type issue.

So nothing is wrong with Facebook updates.